# Cosine similarity vs Cosine distance

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I have a set of documents as given in the example below.

```
doc1 = {'Science': 0, 'History': 0, 'Politics': 0.15,... 'Sports': 0}
doc2 = {'Science': 0.3, 'History': 0.5, 'Politics': 0.1,... 'Sports': 0}
```

I clustered these documents using DBSCAN by using the aforementioned vectors (my vectors are mostly sparse vectors). I get to know that 'cosine similarity' is extremely efficient to compute for sparse vectors. However, according to the sklearn.DBSCAN fit documentation you should use a distance matrix as input to DBSCAN. Hence, I want to know if it is wrong if I used 'cosine similarity' instead of 'cosine distance'.

Please let me know what is the most suitable approach for my problem. Is it DBSCAN using cosine distance **or** DBSCAN using cosine similarity?

```
# Fit DBSCAN using cosine distance
db = DBSCAN(min_samples=1, metric='precomputed').fit(pairwise_distances(feature_matrix, metric='cosine'))
```

**OR**

```
# Fit DBSCAN using cosine similarity
    db = DBSCAN(min_samples=1, metric='precomputed').fit(1-pairwise_distances(feature_matrix, metric='cosine'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a distance matrix it will be O(n²).

If you pass the actual data, the code *could* use an index to make it faster than this. So I'd rather try `metric="cosine"`.

DBSCAN can trivially be implemented with a similarity rather than a distance (c.f. Generalized DBSCAN). I believe I saw this supported in ELKI, but not in sklearn. In sklearn, you can use `cosine_distance` with aforementioned drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you gor the answer :) What you mean is we can't use cosine similarity with DBSCAN implementation in sklearn?

Comment: You can simply use cosine distance instead of similarity. Your epsilon then needs to be a cosine distance, not a cosine similarity, too. But I wouldn't call this "not possible"...

Comment: Can we use `db = DBSCAN(min_samples=1, metric='precomputed').fit(pairwise_distances(feature_matrix, metric='cosine')` ?

Comment: `min_samples` for DBSCAN should be larger than 2, otherwise it is not density based. I do not see any benefit of precomputing the distance matrix. With `metric="cosine"`, the DBSCAN implementation in sklearn may even do exactly this. But a distance matrix needs O(n²) memory, i.e., it scales bad. Why force it to use a bad approach? Let the DBSCAN function decide.

Comment: Note that the question was about cosine *distance* vs. Cosine *similarity*. The code you suggest is also distance, not similarity. Sklearn can already do DBSCAN with cosine *distance*, but not with similarities.

Comment: You are the most commented person for DBSCAN so i believe most knowledgable to answer this. I have tried DBSCAN for 1million data but it fails to execute for memoryerror and didn't find any solution to that yet and there is no clear tutorial for ELKI. Can you help with either an easy tutorial for ELKI or refer to any website for that other than the official site? Or any way to do this in Python itself?

Comment: Tutorials get outdated all the time. I'm good at reading code, so I mostly look at the actual code for examples. The unit tests, for example. But with ELKI, quite a lot can be done in the ugly MiniGUI. Not pretty, but functional.

Comment: I assume you can also use Kotlin, Groovy, Jython or anything else that is JVM based. Jython is python, but AFAIK you cannot use numpy (and thus no sklearn) because it only allows pure Python, no C modules. And numpy is heavily relying on C/Fortran.